# How to make a PHP function that changes an iframe link in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, html

Can someone help me? I want to be able to dynamically modify an iframe src with a PHP function, but I have no idea of how to call the PHP function from WordPress.

[image: iframes]

## Code of Container:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 yt1">
        <iframe width="400" height="200"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bR62ZIPCyv8"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <iframe width="400" height="200"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bR62ZIPCyv8"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <iframe width="400" height="200"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bR62ZIPCyv8"></iframe>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me identify which code I should add, or let me know exactly what I should read up on?

Thanks <3

Comment: Have you tried any PHP code so far? If so, can you post what you tried?

Comment: everything I tried went wrong, code the plugin is clean